# Back up initial, unbooted drive

Tags: backup

I just ordered one of those nifty mini-PCs (Minisforum UM690) which comes pre-loaded with Windows 11.  I will be loading Unbuntu 22.10 on it... but I'm a little nervous about just overwriting that Windows.  I'd like to back it up before I boot it and go thru the initialization.  I can boot Unbuntu from a USB stick, what would I use to back up that the built-in M2 drive?

Comment: Another usb device ( not the one with Ubuntu from which you boot ).

Comment: @JoepieEs - yes, boot from a usb device, write to a different usb device - sorry, but I meant what command to use.  I'm not sure what's available on the bootable usb

Comment: If you choose 'try Ubuntu' the whole operating system is available. You can use the file explorer to copy and paste/cut and paste. You don't need to use the terminal if you don't want to.

Comment: It's preferable to to create a full image (ISO, IMG, etc.) of the drive so you can later return it to factory conditions. You may use Clonezilla, a live system for that and, of course, an additional external drive with enough capacity. And you can  have a dual-boot just by shrinking the Windows partition (it comes with a 512GB drive, plenty for 2, 3 or 4 OSes). Just follow the recommended practices: 1. Disable Fast Startup in Windows and  2. use Windows tools - Disk Management - to resize its main partition (do NOT touch the ESP).

Comment: @ChanganAuto You clarified the question for me - I (now) assume that the disk utility is part of the "Try Ubuntu" - when it makes an image of the drive, does that always include all those "extra" places that a boot drive will have that aren't part of the file system?

Comment: AFAIK Clonezilla isn't included - it can be installed. Clonezilla has live images the same way Ubuntu has.